# Which upgrade should I consider for my usage: RAM or CPU?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, cpu

I plan to buy the new 2017 13" MacBook Pro with Touch Bar for the new semester. However, I'm trying to decide between upgrading the RAM or the CPU.

I'm currently a Math major and plan to use it for things involving maths operations, like running Mathematica, factoring really big primes, graphing 3D contour plots etc. I'm also a bit of a gamer. Another consideration is that I really don't want the computer heating up, as I currently have the fan-less 2015 Retina MacBook and overheating is a common issue.

**With this specific usage in mind, I'm really wondering what would benefit me the most: upgrading to the i7 processor or increasing the RAM to 16GB?**

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to Ask Different! :) I've edited your question to try and reduce the risk of it being closed as being primarily opinion-based (refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). That said, I've offered an answer so that in the event your question is closed you'll still have some info upon which to base your decision. All the best with your studies.

Comment: *...plan to use it for things involving maths operations, like running Mathematica, factoring really big primes, graphing 3D contour plots etc.*  No amount of RAM will speed up calculations.  The CPU is your biggest bang for the buck.  That said, having a dedicated GPU is critical and if I had to do this on a laptop, I would get a mobile *workstation* and Apple doesn't make one of those and as blasphemous as this will sound on this site, I would look at a Dell Precision.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, many users pay too much attention to overheating. Macs are designed to operate at a range of temperatures and to automatically protect themselves if they sense the temperature is above a safe level.

Secondly, you may get differences in opinion, but I'll try my best to answer this with facts.

While some i7 CPUs are quad-core, the ones offered on the 13" MBP are dual-core processors, just like the i5 CPUs.

Since all dual core i5 and i7 mobile processors support hyper-threading, there's actually very little difference between them in terms of a performance gap and battery usage. In fact, both options for this model also incorporate the same Intel Iris Plus Graphics GPU.

My *personal* recommendation would be to upgrade both if you can find a way to afford it, as this will increase it's longevity in terms of future compatibility with software/hardware.

However, if you had to pick and choose what you upgraded, then the upgrade to 16GB RAM would be the most beneficial, as the performance boost on the i7 will benefit you less than the extra RAM would.

Answer (score 0):

The i7 processor for the 2017 13" MacBook Pro is still "just" a dual-core, which is not going to be the ideal MacBook for working with very CPU intensive apps. The base model 2017 15" MacBook Pro has a quad-core i7 processor, which would be more suited to your needs.

Since you're a gamer, getting the 15" model would also make a lot of sense, since you're getting the Radeon Pro 555 graphics card, which will perform noticeably better than the Intel Iris Plus Graphics 650. The 15" MacBook also has a different cooling solution than the 13" MacBook, which should help with alleviating any temperature problems.

In regards to the RAM question, it depends on how much RAM you usually use, which you can find out by opening the Activity Monitor app nd having a look at the Memory tab. RAM is also less important than it has been in previous generations, since caching to SSDs has become much faster due to the very fast SSDs that are included in the new MacBooks. However, more RAM would certainly help with future proofing your purchase.

However, the 15" at $2,399 is $400 more expensive than the 13" inch at $1,999 -  which of course is also a factor to consider, although you can receive a student discount on the MacBooks through the Apple Store.

If you really need the 13" form factor, I would suggest getting the i7 processor, because of what I perceive as your need for more computational power than RAM.

I have the new non Touch Bar 2017 13" MacBook Pro with the 256GB SSD, but I can still get the fans going fairly fast and have it heat up, by just browsing and having a video running in the background. So I believe you will run into very high CPU temperatures doing computational work on the 13" MacBook.